# Probability question about sharing range of quantity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have 10 Boxes, John shares into 7 of them, and Mike shares into 5 boxes.
**The Question :**what is the expected number of boxes are shared between John and Mike?

using equation :7*5 /100 =0.35? then 3.5 is the avg or expected value

Comment: The expected number of shared boxes is $0.35$? It has to be at least $2$: There are $10$ boxes, John shares $7$ of them, leaving only $3$ that Mike can share without John. Since Mike shares $5$ boxes, he must share at least $2$ of the $7$ boxes that John share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a count for those of John alone, b count for those shared by John and Mike, c count for those of Mike alone. Then we have a+b=7,b+c=5, a+b+c=10. Solving we get a=5,b=2 and c=3. The probability is 2/10.

Comment: at least 2, and at maximum =5 so avg = expected = (2+5 )/2=3.5

Comment: why decreasing my rank.?? whyyyyyy